# How to return user input from jQuery UI dialog box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to open a jQuery UI dialog box and the box will have an input field which will take username. I want that when user presses the OK key on the dialog box, the dialog should return the username back to jQuery somehow

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 600,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");}}
        });
```

Comment: You can grab the value put into the box using `val()` as you would any standard input box. Is there something specific you're trying to do with the value?

Comment: ya i want to use it further in my jquery code,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dialog is asynchronous, which makes it meaningless to "return" something.
You can, however, use one of the callback functions to perform actions with the user input.
For example, using the 'OK' button callback:

```
$("#dialog")
    .append(
        $("<input>")
            .attr({
                "type" : "text",
                "id" : "user-input"
            })
    )
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
                alert( $("#user-input").val() );
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }}
    });
```

Comment: so  when i click ok will i be able to access the $("#user-input").val() variable in the jquery script

Comment: yes, because as long as the dialog is open, '#user-input' is part of the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

If you just have a div on your page with ID `dialog` that contains the input field, just select it using a regular jQuery selector when the user presses OK.

Answer (score 1):

Try this on "OK" funcion

```
var myvalue= $("#yourinputtext").val();
alert(myvalue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the value in the `ok` button click handler, and then do with it as your require:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    buttons: {
        "Ok": function() {
            var inputValue = $("#myInput").val();
            // do stuff with the value...

            $(this).dialog("close");}
        }
    }
);
```